# Adding an overall Kaplan Meier curve using autoplot in R

Tags: r, plot, survival-analysis

I have a data frame that looks like this:

`ID Time Censor   Region
 X1  5    4      NorthAmerica
 X2  10   12      Europe
...`

I plot a K-M curve using autoplot via:

`survivalFit <- survfit(Surv(survivalPlotData$Time, survivalPlotData$Censor)~Region, data = survivalPlotData)
autoplot(survivalFit)`

It works fine.

However, I also want to plot an overall KM survival curve on the *same plot* that doesn't differentiate by region. What's the best way to do this?

The only way I found was to basically double the dataframe with another group that says "ALL" and then plot that but this seems terribly inefficient.

Comment: Why wouldn't you remove the predictor variable and replace it with `1` to make a model object that could be handled with autoplot from whatever package it might be found in?

Comment: @42: I did that but then autoplot just plots the one curve. I want to plot all 4 curves at the same time. As far as I know, there's no option for overlay.

Comment: There's only so much I'm willing to do without actual data and code that loads the appropriate packages. I've given up doing searching for all that stuff that questioners should have included.